# How can I size a private std::array member through the constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have a `class B` that is supposed to contain a `private std::array<A*>`, and the size will be *sent in through the constructor*.

```
class B
{
  public:
    B(size_t s) : vv(s,nullptr), aa(s) {}
    // ... more stuff
  private:
    std::vector<A*>   vv;   // vector works fine
    std::array<A*,??> aa;   // but how to initialize an array??
}
```

This works fine with using `std::vector`, but it seems I cannot get it to work with `std::array`.

Adding another member `const size_t ss` and using it in the `std::array` declaration doesn't work either, even if it is a `static const size_t ss` - the compiler (VS2019 16.1.5, set to C++17) claims "...expected compile-time constant..."

```
class B  // another try with a static const size_t
{
  public:
    B(size_t s) : ss(s), aa(s) {}
    // ... more stuff
  private:
    static const size_t ss;
    std::array<A*,ss> aa;   // no, ...expected compile-time constant...
}
```

That message *seems* to imply *there is no way* - if the size needs to be known at compile time, it needs to be *the same* for all instances/objects of the class - which directly contradicts my plan.

Of course, I could make a template class, or I could simply stay with `std::vector`; or I could use a kind of 'PIMPL' (declare instead a pointer to that array, and create it with `new` in the constructor) - that's not the question.

**The question is: Can I pass the size of the to-be array in the constructor, and directly create it from that?**
Is there any fancy construct or trick?

[Note: *not* a duplicate of [Initializing private std::array member in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741720/initializing-private-stdarray-member-in-the-constructor), or [Initializing std::array private member through constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266249/initializing-stdarray-private-member-through-constructor), or [How to construct std::array object with initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893700/how-to-construct-stdarray-object-with-initializer-list) - I don't want to pass *values*, but the *size* of the array]

Comment: Why don't you want to use a vector?

Comment: The size of a `std::array` must be known and specified ***at compile-time***. What the constructor receives is not known until run time. You cannot use `std::array` in this manner, C++ simply does not work this way.

Comment: `vector` works fine, sure. I'd like to learn if I could use `array` in this context. I understand there is no or infinitesimal performance or memory gain - it's purely _educational_.

Comment: Well, you just received the education that says that you cannot use `std::array` in this context. That's not what it's used for.

Comment: And thanks. It already became a lot clearer by simply _writing_ the question up - but after that effort I didn't want to throw it all away. It could help someone else too.

Comment: You could try a template, or possibly maybe even a `constexpr`. But `constexpr` is a long shot.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. The size of std::array is determined at compile time, and not runtime. For runtime storage, use std::vector. The closest you can get to with a class, is to declare the class as a template, like so:

```
template<size_t size>
class Foo {
   std::array<size> member;
};
```

But if you want to pass the size as an arg to the constructor, you'll need to use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can "pretend" to pass the size to the constructor.

```
template <size_t Size>
struct array_size_t {};

template <size_t Size>
constexpr array_size_t<Size> array_size {};

template <size_t Size>
class Foo {
public:
  explicit Foo(array_size_t<Size>) {}

private:
  std::array<int, Size> arr;
};

Foo foo{array_size<12>};
```

Not sure why you would want to use this code because `Foo<12> foo;` is much shorter than `Foo foo{array_size<12>};`.